# Android 4.2.1 issue drawing multiple paths on Google Maps MapView Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, android-mapview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am making an application that involves drawing one to many lines using GPS data on a Google Maps MapView.  To accomplish this, I use a custom Overlay and construct an ArrayList of Paths.  The paths are made up of points that are created from a set of GeoPoints.  After the GeoPoints are converted to Points, the Paths are created and added to the ArrayList and the Paths are drawn by iterating through said ArrayList.  All of this is being done in the draw() method of my custom Overlay.

Now, all of this is working just fine on every device that I have tested *except* those that are running the latest Android Jellybean release, 4.2.1.  On those devices, only the last path in the ArrayList is being drawn.  I have checked the process over and over with Log outputs, and it's almost acting as if the previous paths are simply invisible because the data is all still there and appearing as though it should be drawing.  I have tested this out on multiple 4.2.1 devices, and behaves the same on all of them.  I had some pictures to illustrate this problem, but I do not have sufficient reputation to post images.

I have not been able to find any useful information on the rest of the internet.  Does anybody have any sort of insight as to what on Earth the problem could be?

Comment: hi. It's not a fix for the specific problem you're facing, but the Maps API V2 for Android is so much easier to do then creating custom overlay, etc. Maybe you should give it a try. It's really as simple as making a for loop with a addLine() instruction.

Comment: Though it has been a while since I asked, your suggestion to make the move to Map API v2 was very helpful.  I no longer encountered the issue and absolutely everything is so much easier! (except for taking a screenshot of the map)